# In .js.erb file only one condition is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

In .js.erb file only one condition is working.

```
var price = <%= @price %> // assigned for substitution, dont take this a concern
<%- if @price.nil? %>
   alert("if");
  // JS code if true
<%- else %>
   alert("else");
  // JS code if false
<%- end %>
```

On inspecting the console

In `@price` have any of the following.

1. nil
2. 0.00333333

alert inside `else` is only working. If I have `@price=nil` alert is not working. Am I doing any thing wrong in syntax.

**Answer:**

The following code worked.

```
if (price == "") {
 alert("if"); 
}
else {
  alert("else");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because if your price is nil than below code is generated

```
var price = nil // assigned for substitution, dont take this a concern
```

which will give you error `nil is not defined`

so instead of echoing `nil` value echo `false or 0`

Note: Don't forget to put semilcolon in javascript

```
var price = <%= @price %>;
```

**EDITED**

Their are two Case for you

**Case 1** : If @price is nil. so your ouput generated will be something like this

```
    var price = nil // assigned for substitution, dont take this a concern
    // above line will give you error nil is not defined
    alert("if")
```

**Case 2** : If @price is 22. so your ouput generated will be something like this

```
    var price = 22 // assigned for substitution, dont take this a concern
    alert("else")
    // will work perfectly fine.
```

Comment: Can't understand what you would like to say?

Comment: check what <%= @price %> print if price is nil

Comment: so your output will be same which I have given in answer. so their is nothing like nil in javascript

Comment: Your answer is similar. Updated answer